# deleting a text from QtextEdit after pressing a pushbutton Pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

this a chatbot using chatterbot i m trying to delete the text that the user writes in textEdit once he clicks a pushbutton or presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> like tkinter you can do like: `msgs.insert(END, "You : " + query)` and it deletes the text once the button is pressed

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from chatterbot import ChatBot
bot = ChatBot('butty bot')

trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(bot)

trainer.train("chatterbot.corpus.english")


bot = ChatBot('butty bot')

trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(bot)

trainer.train("chatterbot.corpus.english")

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(402, 659)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        def action():
            query = self.textEdit.toPlainText()
            response = bot.get_response(query)
            self.listbox.addItem("You : " + query)
            self.listbox.addItem("Butty bot : " + str(response))

        self.send_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.send_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 550, 111, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.send_btn.setFont(font)
        self.send_btn.setObjectName("send_btn")
        self.send_btn.clicked.connect(action)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 10, 121, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Lucida Fax")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 510, 381, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.textEdit.setFont(font)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
```

Comment: Do you mean something like [`self.textEdit.clear()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#clear)?

Comment: yes @musicamante

Comment: i m getting this error `TypeError: clear(self): too many arguments`

Comment: Without any context about what you actually did and how, it's really impossible to help you with that. Explain yourself, or update your question accordingly.